# Can one override accent keys behavior in javascript?

Tags: javascript, keypress, diacritics

For certain foreign keyboards (German, Swedish) when one wants to write accented letters (á, ñ, ê) one would first press one of the accent keys (<kbd>´</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>) followed by the letter to have that accent. But if one presses it once no `input` is sent until one either presses it again or another letter, and the `input` gets that combination. What I'd like to know is if there is some way to detect when one of these... "sticky keys" are pressed then override the default behavior and "un-stick" the key, and display the accent on its own?

Comment: The behaviour you describe is implemented in the operating system. While adding listeners for `keydown` (as described in the answer) could be possible, telling the OS to not combine the two keys into a new character is something that is beyond the abilities of a JavaScript application running in the browser (because it requires direct interaction with the OS on a lower level than a JavaScript application has access to). It is probably possible in a native application and the exact way to do it depends on the operating system where the application runs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event listeners on the input element:

For ` you can do something like:

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown",(event)=>{
  console.log(event.keyCode)
})
```

Then you can test it and see what the desired keycode is for your key and then adjust the code to something like this:

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown",(event)=>{
  if(event.keyCode==x){ //x is your keycode
    //do something
  }
})
```

The keycode of ` is 192.

For the other two it is harder because you need to keep track if shift is being pressed:

```
  let shiftPressed = false;
  document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown",(event)=>{
    if (event.keyCode == 16){ //shift
      shiftPressed=true
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 54 && shiftPressed){ // for ^
      // ^
      // do some things
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 192 && shiftPressed){ // for ~
      // ~
      // do some things
    }
  })
  document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
    if (event.keyCode == 16){ //shift
      shiftPressed=false
    }
  })
```

To add them on their own you can change the value of the input element like this:

```
document.getElementById("input").value +="`"
```

Edit:

To prevent the browser from adding another set of `` you can call event.preventDefault.

This gives the total code (reformatted for variable input instead of calling document.getElementById multiple times):

```
let shiftPressed = false;
const input = document.getElementById("input")
input.addEventListener("keydown",(event)=>{
  if (event.keyCode == 16){ //shift
    shiftPressed=true
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 54 && shiftPressed){ // for ^
    event.preventDefault()
    input.value+= "^"
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 192 && shiftPressed){ // for ~
    event.preventDefault()
    input.value+= "~"
  }
  else if(event.keyCode == 192){
    event.preventDefault()
    input.value+= "`"
  }
})
input.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
  if (event.keyCode == 16){ //shift
    shiftPressed=false
  }
})
```

Comment: Ok, this was useful information. `preventDefault()` didn't really unstick the key, and axiac pretty much confirmed I can't do it at all in js. However testing the keyCodes shows that `^` is 221 on this keyboard. Some other solution is gonna be needed here...